# PowerShell to create a list of AD-users and properties from csv of samAccountNames

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a list of users with other AD properties (Name, sAC, Description) from a file with only samAccountName for each user.

When I try this:

```
$file=import-csv "C:\newtest.csv"
$file | ForEach-Object {
get-aduser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Properties * | Select-Object Name, samAccountName, Description|Export-Csv C:\newerTest.csv
}
```

I get an error "Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'..."

I've used other Stack Questions to also try building it with -Filter as so:

```
$file=import-csv "C:\newtest.csv"
ForEach-Object {
Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '*$($_samAccountName)*'" -Properties * | Select-Object Name, samAccountName, Description|Export-Csv C:\newerTest.csv
}
```

but that gives me a "search filter not recognized" error.

TY for any help!

Comment: have you confirmed that your CSV has a column with that name? if so, then check that the value is valid - no trailing spaces, for instance.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes, I have a column with the header 'samAccountName' and checked numerous values and no spaces. What's really odd, is that the very last value will work.

Comment: i see that you found & fixed your errors. kool! glad to know that you got it all working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I get an error "Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'..."
```

On the top line of the CSV you have to have "samAccountName" so pick the right column.  What happens when you type **$file.samAccountName** ?

> but that gives me a "search filter not recognized" error.

I can not check right now, but it looks like you are missing a "." between $_ and samAccountName. You also were missing "$file |"

```
$file=import-csv "C:\newtest.csv"
$file | ForEach-Object {
Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '*$($_.samAccountName)*'" -Properties * | Select-Object Name, samAccountName, Description|Export-Csv C:\newerTest.csv
}
```

Comment: What happens when you type $file.samAccountName ?

Comment: Nothing returns...hmmm

Comment: Oh just figured out the headers had some weird formatting going on so I re-typed them. It works now, but it's only actually writing the last account in the list to the new csv.

Comment: -append after export to csv fixed the overwrite issue. Thanks Aaron for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use your's first variant of code

```
$file=import-csv C:\newtest.csv
$file | ForEach-Object {
get-aduser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Properties * | Select-Object Name, samAccountName, Description|Export-Csv C:\newerTest.csv
}
```

But in your file C:\newtest.csv first line must called samAccountName, then in row SAmacc of your users.